# Can I avoid case sensitivity problems when comparing element tagName?

Tags: javascript, dom

Because [`HTMLElement.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName) property case differs depending on XHTML/HTML I keep using:

```
 if(element.tagName.toLowerCase()=="div")
 //Or, if I feel big
 if(element.tagName.toUpperCase()=="DIV")
```

Generally, I really don't like performing operations on strings, especially in languages that use immutable strings.

I could however, avoid strings completely by using `instanceof` operator. This solution is not supported in older versions of IE which I don't care about:

```
if(element instanceof HTMLDivElement)
```

So my questions are:

1. Can the first solution be performed smarter?
2. Can I use the second solution with no fear if I only care about current versions of browsers? (and is it actually faster?)

Comment: If you're fine with using jQuery instead of just vanilla JavaScript, you could also try [the `is` function](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Comment: I'm quite sure this function performs string operation from my first solution. And no, I don't use jQuery for things that can be done in a native way without considerable loss of readability.

Comment: It's largely a matter of taste when it comes to `considerable loss` and `smarter`. The solution is much shorter and has a well-documented browser support. Then again, I'm far from advocating the use of jQuery as a cure for all of the world's problems... Which has a next to memetic history here on stackoverflow.

Comment: It seems that using `instanceof` is faster (in Chrome 35, Windows 8.1): [JS Perf test](http://jsperf.com/element-type-determination).

Comment: So is in firefox. It's also interesting to see, that converting upper case string to upper case is way faster than the other way.

Comment: I saw the same thing in Chrome (but didn't think to draw attention to it); it does seem somewhat surprising that either `toLowerCase()` *or* `toUpperCase()` would be any faster/slower than the other though.

Comment: Interestingly, despite your reaction to [Dalorzo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855630/can-i-avoid-case-sensitivity-problems-when-comparing-element-tagname#comment36714786_23855785) (deleted, below) regex is *not* the slowest solution (Chrome 35/Windows 8.1) that honour remains with the `toLowerCase()` approach: [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/element-type-determination) (at the same URL as before, but repeated to prevent comment-searching).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're not using XHTML, there is no reason to do a case-check. HTML will *always* return `tagName` in uppercase.

In case you're writing something which has to work both with XHTML and HTML, then you can just convert the string to upper or lower case as your initial example. There is no reason to avoid string operations like this - and there is no reason to avoid string operations in languages with immutable strings either.

Using `instanceof` is also an acceptable method of doing this, as long as you're aware of the limitations with IE and such as you mentioned.

Comment: Well, certain operations (like concatenation) are better performed on something else than string. But sure, immutability has no effect on string comparison.

Comment: It depends on how the operation is implemented on the language level, and also how often you're doing it. Even if there is a performance difference, in 99% of cases, there is little benefit from doing tricks to avoid string ops because the difference is so trivial.

Comment: My question was partialy asking whether `instanceof` is considered *trick* or legit thing. I can now see that I have asked question that may not have one answer...

Comment: `instanceof` is a reasonable approach in my opinion :)